# ¿Como añadir un registro en un archivo xml usando la bilbioteca lxml en python?

Tags: python, xml

Hola estoy intentando hacer un programa de forma interactiva y ocupo agregar mas registros de un contacto por ejemplo tengo el siguiente código que me genera el árbol:

```
from lxml import etree as ET
def insert(alias, userName, userMiddleName, userLastName):  
 contacts = ET.Element('contacts')
 contac = ET.SubElement(contacts, 'contac')
 contac.set('alias', alias)
 
 #Etiqueta name
 name = ET.SubElement(contac, 'name')
 first = ET.SubElement(name, 'first')
 first.text = userName
 middle = ET.SubElement(name, 'middle')
 middle.text = userMiddleName
 last = ET.SubElement(name, 'last')
 last.text = userLastName
```

Genero el archivo con:

```
file = ET.ElementTree(contacts)
file.write('prueba.xml',pretty_print=True, encoding='UTF-8')
```

Resultado xml:

```
<contacts>
 <contac alias="lalo">
  <name>
   <first>Eduardo</first>
   <middle></middle>
   <last>Ramirez</last>
 </name>
</contac>
```

Quisiera introducir otro contacto dentro de la etiqueta contactos sin que me sobrescriba el archivo, tengo entendido que write sobreescribe y que existe el metodo append() pero creo funciona de manera diferente alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te propongo la siguiente solución. El método `add_contact` añade un nuevo contacto al elemento `tag`. De este modo puedes añadir los contactos que desees. Finalmente para guardar el xml puedes utilizar el método `write`

```
from lxml import etree as ET

def add_contact(contacts, alias, userName, userMiddleName, userLastName):  
    contac = ET.SubElement(contacts, 'contac')
    contac.set('alias', alias)
    name = ET.SubElement(contac, 'name')
    first = ET.SubElement(name, 'first')
    first.text = userName
    middle = ET.SubElement(name, 'middle')
    middle.text = userMiddleName
    last = ET.SubElement(name, 'last')
    last.text = userLastName
    # INSERT
    contacts.append(contac)

 
contacts = ET.Element('contacts')
add_contact(contacts, 'lalo', 'Eduardo', '', 'Ramirez')
add_contact(contacts, 'dmiro', 'David', 'Miro', '')


with open('c:/distancias/output.xml', 'wb') as f:
    doc = ET.ElementTree(contacts)
    doc.write(f, xml_declaration=True, pretty_print=True, encoding='UTF-8')
```

Resultado:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<contacts>
  <contac alias="lalo">
    <name>
      <first>Eduardo</first>
      <middle></middle>
      <last>Ramirez</last>
    </name>
  </contac>
  <contac alias="dmiro">
    <name>
      <first>David</first>
      <middle>Miro</middle>
      <last></last>
    </name>
  </contac>
</contacts>
```